# C# Xamarin Cross Platform

Tags: c#, listview, cross-platform

My first question here.

Here is the deal:

I'm trying to settle a Listview that would bring me all the names of some businesses registered in one event.

The codes are bellow:

First I creatted a Model

```
public class BusinessReg
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String BusinessName { get; set; }
    public String BusinessFantasyName { get; set; }
    public String BusinessArea { get; set; }
    public String BusinessSpecificArea { get; set; }
    public String Country { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String Adress { get; set; }
    public String Neighbourhood { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }
    public String Complement { get; set; }
    public Double Latitude { get; set; }
    public Double Longitude { get; set; }
    public String DateOfReg { get; set; }
    public String DateOfMod { get; set; }
    public String BusinessStatus { get; set; }
    public String RegisteredBy { get; set; }
}
```

Than I creatted another Class called Services

```
public class BusinessRegServices
{
    public List<BusinessReg> GetBusinessReg()

    {
        var list = new List<BusinessReg>
        {
            new BusinessReg
            {
                BusinessName = "Casadafarofa",
                BusinessFantasyName = "casa da farofa2",
                BusinessArea ="restaurante",
                BusinessSpecificArea = "Casas de Farofaria",
                Country ="brazil",
                State = "RS",
                City = "Rio Grande",
                Adress = "avenida Rio Grande",
                Neighbourhood = "Cassino",
                Number= "1420",
                Complement ="",
                Latitude = 23,
                Longitude = 25,
                DateOfReg ="23/09/1984",
                DateOfMod ="27/12/1986",
                BusinessStatus ="Ativo",
                RegisteredBy = "Zé das couves"
            },

            new BusinessReg
            {
                BusinessName = "Casadafarofa3",
                BusinessFantasyName = "casa da farofa4",
                BusinessArea ="restaurante2",
                BusinessSpecificArea = "Casas de Farofaria2",
                Country ="brazil2",
                State = "RS2",
                City = "Rio Grande2",
                Adress = "avenida Rio Grande2",
                Neighbourhood = "Cassino2",
                Number= "14202",
                Complement ="2",
                Latitude = 23.1,
                Longitude =25,
                DateOfReg ="23/09/1984",
                DateOfMod ="27/12/1986",
                BusinessStatus ="Ativo",
                RegisteredBy = "Zé das couves"
            }
        };
        return list;
    }
}
```

And than I Created a View Class as bellow

```
public class BusinessRegView
{
    public List<BusinessReg> BusinessRegList { get; set; }

    public BusinessRegView()
    {
        var businessRegServices = new BusinessRegServices();

        BusinessRegList = businessRegServices.GetBusinessReg();
    }
};
```

On my Mainpage (C# only) I'm trying to list the two business names, but It comes blank page.

```
public class Config : ContentPage
{
    public Config ()
    {

        BindingContext = new BusinessRegView();

        ListView Lista = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = "{Binding BusinessName}"
        };
             new ScrollView
             {

                Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

                Content = Lista,
              },
```

Could anyone help me What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for all.

Daniel.

Comment: *Could anyone help me What I'm doing wrong?* Apparently nothing is wrong here. Otherwise, you would have described in your question *what you expected to happen* then *what actually happened*, and finally *why that doesn't work for you*.  Of course, you could always [edit] and add that information. Maybe even an exception message or two. Make it less hard to answer your question, you know. Guessing at what's going on is never what you want answerers to spend their time doing. You want them to spend their time answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
ItemsSource = "{Binding BusinessName}"
```

You can use the {Binding ...} notation in a XAML file but not in Code. Here you have to set the ItemsSource to your Collection like:

```
ItemsSource = businessRegServices.GetBusinessReg();
```

Or something like this...

You also need to define an item template, otherwise you will see only empty entries...

Comment: Hello Markus. first of all, thanks for your Comment. Very useful.
Here is what I did in my contente page:
    
            BindingContext = new BusinessRegView();

            var businessRegServices = new BusinessRegServices();


            ListView Lista = new ListView
            {

                ItemsSource = businessRegServices.GetBusinessReg(),

 

            };

But Now the content thar is shown is two lines written Icquire.Models.BusinessReg

I want to show in this lines the Actual BusinessName. Could you help me how to make it? 

Thanks in advance.
Daniel.

Comment: Hello Daniel, you have to define an ItemTemplate. I recommend reading the Xamarin docs. They are really good and clear (at least most of them)... e.g.: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/standard/ or https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/ or read the WPF XAML docs to get a deeper knowledge of XAML e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf